# Which parameter from the datasheet of a Zener diode should I consider for voltage regulation?

Tags: diodes, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, zener

I am using a 4.7V (1N4732A) Zener diode to regulate input voltage from 24V to 5V for an Arduino input. Everything works perfectly. I am not really sure how.

Which current parameter in the datasheet should I consider when using a Zener diode for voltage regulation?

[image]

Comment: What does the picture explain other than that you have too much load current through the 510 ohm resistor or, too much resistance in the 22k resistor?

Comment: @bcicek:  You could remove the Zener diode from your diagram and you would still get about 0.54 volts at the junction of the 22k resistor and the 510 ohm resistor.  You have a voltage divider that makes 0.54 volts with a Zener diode in parallel with part of the divider.

Comment: *I am using a ... Zener diode to regulate input voltage from 24V to 5V for an Arduino input.* For us EEs, "input voltage" means that you only want to **sense** that the 24 V is there (or not) and that you do not intend to **power** the Arduino like this as that **will not work**. Even if you remove the 510 Ohm resistor that is now preventing your circuit from working as you want it to. I think some **studying** is required so that you learn more about **shunt regulators**. And if you do want to power that Arduino from 24 V, use a **voltage regulator** IC or module.

Comment: Are you SENSING the 24V or hoping to POWER something? Without the 510R you will get about I= V/R =  (Vin-Vzener)/ 22k ~= 0.9 mA. Fine for sensing. No good for power. | Remove the 510 Ohm in yuour simulation and see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Zener diode has three datasheet values to consider; one, is a package-related power limit; second, a recommended bias current.  Third, is the dynamic impedance (the equivalent resistance for small signals when under bias).   Bias current, in the above circuit, is nil, so it isn't really
regulating at 4.7V at all.

Accuracy of the voltage at the Zener cathode has two terms: one is the
unit-to-unit variation allowed by the manufacturer, the other is the
current variation (if any) drawn by the Zener times the dynamic impedance of the diode.

For a 4.7V Zener, a 0.5V terminal voltage indicates the bias current
is not sufficient to achieve regulation.  1N4732A is a typical
4.7V Zener diode, and at 53 mA bias (24V source and 360 ohm, 1W resistor)
its equivalent resistance is about 8 ohms.

That makes it a good regulator of its output voltage, since the
fluctuations of the 24V supply only connect through higher (360 ohm)
resistance than the 8 ohm value.   It also wastes quite
a lot of electrical power, which is why the 1W rating of the
resistor is important.

That diode can, with air cooling, take up to 1W, so the bias current
could be raised to 200 mA, allowing zero to 150 mA delivered to the load,
while remaining a 'good' regulator.   That would mean a pullup resistor
of about 100 ohms, rated for 4W,  however.